# Does an android widget run in the same process as it's app

Tags: android, android-widget, android-service

I want to create a bound service for my app and would like it to be available for a widget to use in the future should i decide to create one. In order to decide whether to use a Messenger or extend Binder i need to know whether a widget and its corresponding app run in the same process?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. Unless you specify otherwise in the manifest (using `android:process="..."`), all components of an application (widget providers, services, activities, broadcast receivers) run in the same process, use the same Virtual Machine and run in the same memory space.

Comment: However, the *UI* of the app widget, defined in the form of a `RemoteViews` structure, is rendered by the home screen's process (or by the lockscreen's process in the case of lockscreen widgets).