# Does Android App Widgets run in the application process or host process?

Tags: android, process, widget, android-appwidget

I'm a little confused about in which process an App Widget is running by default.
Over at Android Developers i read:

> "Every application runs in its own process and all components of the application run in that process, by default" - From: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

My textbook says:

> "Android App Widgets do not run in the application process, but in the host’s process.
>   Therefore, the App Widget uses the RemoteViews class to define its user interface.The
>   RemoteViews class supports a subset of the overall View hierarchy, for display in another
>   process. Generally speaking, you want to configure the RemoteViews object and send it
>   to the App Widget Manager during the onUpdate() method. However, you also need
>   to update it when an instance is created and a configuration activity exists." From: Android Wireless Application Development Volume II 3rd Edition, page 370

Someone also asked this question before and the answer is "same process":
[Does an android widget run in the same process as it's app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016944/does-an-android-widget-run-in-the-same-process-as-its-app)

Can someone please help me understand if an Android App Widget runs in its own process or in the same as the main applikation. Thanks

Comment: Seems easy enough to check. Just make a logcat entry from each and compare the PIDs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does an android widget run in the same process as it's app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016944/does-an-android-widget-run-in-the-same-process-as-its-app)

Answer (score 9):

That depends on what you think an "Android App Widget" actually is:

- If you think that an app widget is a bit of UI that runs on the home screen, that UI is being rendered by the home screen's process.
- If you think that an app widget is a subclass of `AppWidgetProvider`, then that runs in your own app's process.

The app widget system is a plugin mechanism. The home screen, with the assistance of the Android framework, requests `RemoteViews` objects from the `AppWidgetProvider`. Those `RemoteViews` represent the UI to be rendered by the home screen. However, the work to *create* that `RemoteViews` will be in your process, as with any other of your app components. And usually the work to process click events will route to your process via a `PendingIntent`.